# How to put Keyword filter on Contacts?

Tags: audience-manager

I need to put a keyword filter on my contacts list. I am using Audience Manager API.
Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am using Audience Manager.API for getting the contact list from an address book. I got the list but I need some selective contacts who are tagged with one of the keyword.

Comment: Keywords have a 'WhereUsed' feature.  If you select the keyword in Tridion and then WhereUsed, do you see your contacts?  If so, you could do the same via the API and then maybe also filter on the ItemType = keyword.

Comment: @robrtc - I don't think where used applies to contacts (maybe as they are stored in a different DB). You can even delete a keyword that is linked to contacts without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the `Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.ContactFilter` class. This has a `Keywords` property you can use to filter a list of contacts from an address book.

Comment: Listen to this man :)